# Sort By Matched Subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Say I have a collection with documents that look like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
    "users": [{
        "userId": ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
        "deleted": false,
        "updatedAt" ISODate("2013-10-17T20:46:22Z")
    }, {
        "userId": ObjectId("507f1f71baf40ea8438490fa"),
        "deleted": false,
        "updatedAt" ISODate("2013-10-17T22:19:10Z")
    }]
}
```

Now, assume that I am querying for a document which has a "users" subdocument containing a specific userId, which isn't deleted - so, a query looking like:

```
{"users.userId": ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"), "users.deleted": false}
```

Would it be possible to then sort the returned resultset by the `updatedAt` attribute of the matched subdocument in the row? If not, is there a more appropriate way of setting this up? Should I just create another collection of what I currently have embedded in the `users` key, and then have that reference the parent document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can try this:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {$unwind:"$users"},
 {$match:{"users.userId":"ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011")","users.deleted":false}},
 {$sort:{"users.updatedAt":1}}])
```

Here 'collection' is to be replaced by the name of your collection.

Comment: If I have an index defined as: `{"users.userId": 1, "users.deleted": 1, "users.updatedAt": -1}`, would that index cover this query? This would be commonly run, so if it makes more sense to bring this out into a separate collection for performance reasons - I'd rather do that.

Comment: @ColinMorelli but you can still test it, to be sure.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an explain for aggregate queries yet, so it's hard to tell of this will hit an index. In any case - this is as close as I will be getting with the current document structure - so I think I'd consider this answered.

Comment: I also was unaware that the aggregation framework counts as a single document, and thus the entire resultset of the aggregation is subject to the 16MB document limit

Comment: @ColinMorelli so will this limit create a problem for your structure?

Comment: It *may* be. There's no application limit on the number of results that a single user may have, so I can't guarantee that it would be less than 16MB (although, practically, it SHOULD be). It's looking like it will be better for me to split my documents up.